# Maximum Bipartite Graph Matching with some exclusive edges

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory

I am trying to solve a bipartite graph problem but I cannot find anything for graphs with some exclusive edges. Say each node on the right can accept 3 normal left nodes or 1 exclusive left node.

I have tried modifying the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm from GeeksForGeeks, however the issue I have is when removing multiple nodes at once. For example, 0, 1, 2* are the left nodes where 2* is exclusive. A and B are the right nodes. 0 and 1 will go to A, 2* will go to attempt to go to A and should kick 0 and 1 to B, however if only 0 could actually fit in B, then the algorithm falls over. Do I need to use a different algorithm or am I thinking about this wrong? Thanks for the help

Comment: Are there any caps or proportions you can give? E.g., max number of right & left nodes, and the proportion of left nodes that are normal vs exclusive. Also, do you know that a solution exists that connects every left node with a right node? If not, how would you choose a winner between two possibilities? (# matched nodes, or maybe favoring exclusive or normal nodes)?

Comment: I can guarantee that a perfect match exists. I'm using the Edmonds-Karp algorithm at the moment. For every 3 normal edges there is a corresponding exclusive edge. So the capacity of the normal node is 3 and the capacity of the exclusive edge is 1 and they go into the same node. The best solution I have at the moment is to ignore exclusivity and at the end kick all conflicts, but that is not optimal at all

Comment: What I can do is run the algorithm and ignore the exclusivity restrictions. Then I can find all conflict pairs and remove one of the edges and run the algorithm again and check if the flow is the same. The tricky part is knowing which edge of the pair to remove, as there will be thousands

Comment: Just noodling on this, have you tried giving edges incident with exclusive nodes a weight of 3, and modifying Edmonds-Karp BFS portion to look for edges where cap > flow (as usual), but also cap == 1 or flow == 0?

Comment: I did think of giving the exclusive edges a weight of 3, then I could add an inbetween node with a capacity of 3. That way the flow algorithm could only allow one of them to get through. The problem with that is I need it to have a capacity of 1 for other reasons in the problem, only 10 items should be able to flow into another node, if the exclusive edges have a weight of 3 then that doesn't work for it. It's possible that I could modify something to fix that though, but I'm not sure what